# Time complexity of naïve merge of two binary search trees

Tags: algorithm, merge, time-complexity, binary-search-tree, asymptotic-complexity

I saw a very short algorithm for merging two binary search trees. I was surprised how easy and also very inefficient it is. But when I tried to guess its time complexity, I failed.

Lets have a two immutable binary search trees (not balanced) that contains integers and you want to merge them together with the following recursive algorithm in pseudo code. Function `insert` is auxiliary:

```
function insert(Tree t, int elem) returns Tree:
    if elem < t.elem:
        return new Tree(t.elem, insert(t.leftSubtree, elem), t.rightSubtree)
    elseif elem > t.elem:
        return new Tree(t.elem, t.leftSubtree, insert(t.rightSubtree, elem))
    else
        return t

function merge(Tree t1, Tree t2) returns Tree:
    if t1 or t2 is Empty:
        return chooseNonEmpty(t1, t2)
    else
        return insert(merge(merge(t1.leftSubtree, t1.rightSubtree), t2), t1.elem)
```

I guess its an exponencial algorithm but I cannot find an argument for that. What is the worst time complexity of this merge algorithm?

Comment: Why exactly do you say the algo is ineffective?

Comment: @displayName Insert one tree into another would be O(n^3). But this is maybe like O(n^n), because for each node it traverses a whole tree again to the bottom. And then all once again (second call of merge)…

Comment: @greybeard Yes, "inefficient" would be a better word, I changed the title. I used the word "effective" within the meaning of "available for useful work", not as a term of computability theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the *worst* case:

> At each stage every tree is in the *maximally* imbalanced state, i.e. each node has at least one sub-tree of size 1.

In this extremal case the complexity of `insert` is quite easily shown to be `Ө(n)` where `n` is the number of elements in the tree, as the height is `~ n/2`.

---

Based on the above constraint, we can deduce a recurrence relation for the time complexity of `merge`:

[image]

where `n, m` are the sizes of `t1, t2`. It is assumed without loss of generality that the right sub-tree always contains a single element. The terms correspond to:

- `T(n - 2, 1)`: the inner call to `merge` on the sub-trees of `t1`
- `T(n - 1, m)`: the outer call to `merge` on `t2`
- `Ө(n + m)`: the final call to `insert`

---

To solve this, let's re-substitute the first term and observe a pattern:

[image]

We can solve this sum by stripping out the first term:

[image]

Where in step `(*)` we used a change-in-variable substitution `i -> i + 1`. The recursion stops when `k = n`:

[image]

`T(1, m)` is just the insertion of an element into a tree of size `m`, which is obviously `Ө(m)` in our assumed setup.

> Therefore the *absolute worst-case* time complexity of `merge` is
>
> [image]

---

Notes:

- The order of the parameters matters. It is thus common to insert the smaller tree into the larger tree (in a manner of speaking).
- Realistically you are extremely unlikely to have maximally imbalanced trees at *every* stage of the procedure. The average case will naturally involve semi-balanced trees.
- The *optimal* case (i.e. always perfectly balanced trees) is much more complex (I am unsure that an analytical solution like the above exists; see `gdelab`'s answer).

---

EDIT: *How to evaluate the exponential sum*

Suppose we want to compute the sum:

[image]

where `a, b, c, n` are positive constants. In the second step we changed the base to `e` (the *natural* exponential constant). With this substitution we can treat `ln c` as a variable `x`, differentiate a *geometrical progression* with respect to it, then set `x = ln c`:

[image]

But the geometrical progression has a closed-form solution (a standard formula which is not difficult to derive):

[image]

And so we can differentiate this result with respect to `x` by `n` times to obtain an expression for `Sn`. For the problem above we only need the first two powers:

[image]

So that troublesome term is given by:

[image]

which is exactly what Wolfram Alpha directly quoted. As you can see, the basic idea behind this was simple, although the algebra was incredibly tedious.

Comment: Whoa, thank you very much for your solution! Clever handling of all those sums! I got stuck at second equation from the back, where you are getting rid of sum of 2^(j-1) * Omega(…) between 1 and n-2. I have no clue from where you got 11*2^(n-2)+….

Comment: @MartinJiřička ah yes, that sum can be quite easily done with a mathematical trick, but I was too lazy to do it explicitly so I just used Wolfram Alpha :D sorry for the confusion; if you would like me to include how such a sum can be computed please let me know

Comment: Yes, I am interested! You can only post a name of the trick if it has some, I will try to compute it myself. Thank you! (And if it will be correct, I would mark your solution as answer ;-D)

Comment: @MartinJiřička done. Let me know if there is anything you still don't understand

Comment: I apologize it took me so long to review your answer. To be honest I wasn't able to follow your solution completely, it is too high math for me. Anyway, thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to compute exactly, but it looks like it's not polynomially bounded in the worst case (this is not a complete proof however, you'd need a better one):

- insert has complexity `O(h)` at worst, where `h` is the height of the tree (i.e. at least `log(n)`,possibly `n`).
- The complexity of merge() could then be of the form: `T(n1, n2) = O(h) + T(n1 / 2, n1 / 2) + T(n1 - 1, n2)`
- let's consider `F(n)` such that `F(1)=T(1, 1)` and `F(n+1)=log(n)+F(n/2)+F(n-1)`. We can probably show that `F(n)` is smaller than `T(n, n)` (since `F(n+1)` contains `T(n, n)` instead of `T(n, n+1)`).
- We have `F(n)/F(n-1) = log(n)/F(n-1) + F(n/2) / F(n-1) + 1`
- Assume `F(n)=Theta(n^k)` for some `k`. Then  `F(n/2) / F(n-1) >= a / 2^k` for some `a>0` (that comes from the constants in the `Theta`).
- Which means that (beyond a certain point `n0`) we always have `F(n) / F(n-1) >= 1 + epsilon` for some fixed `epsilon > 0`, which is not compatible with `F(n)=O(n^k)`, hence a contradiction.
- So `F(n)` is not a `Theta(n^k)` for any `k`. Intuitively, you can see that the problem is probably not the `Omega` part but the `big-O` part, hence it's probably not a `O(n)` (but technically we used the `Omega` part here to get `a`). Since `T(n, n)` should be even bigger than `F(n)`, *`T(n, n)` should not be polynomial*, and is maybe exponential...

But then again, this is not rigorous at all, so maybe I'm actually dead wrong...

Comment: Hmm, I will need some time to chew it over… Theta and Omega are well known functions from complexity theory? (I haven't listened about them.)

Comment: Omega is like the reciprocal of big-O, and F=Theta(g) iff F=O(g) and F=Omega(g). See [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-big-omega-notation) for instance.